# Copy Value as Number to Text VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a number over as text, as there are leading `0`s that I need to keep in the value...

I've tried using below and it's copying over as a number and not as text...

```
DestinationRange.cells(1).value = SourceRange(2).text
```

The value I'm copying over it `000076` and the end result is giving me `76` however, like I said above, I need to **keep** the leading `0`s

Comment: You will also need to use `DestinationRange.cells(1).NumberFormat = "000000"`

Comment: Doing this really slows down my code by quite a bit as there is anywhere from 30 and up to 20,000 cells to be copied. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Then after the loop is done, set the numberformat of the entire column.

Comment: Did that, and it's working fine now. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.NumberFormat = "000000"` for the entire column after the loop is done.